# How to get rid of rust target [Windows]

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo, rustup

For some reason the thumbv7m-none-eabi target is in every rust project i create
I have reinstalled rust completely (from the uninstaller and deleting .cargo and .rustup)

rustup show:

```
rustup home:  C:\Users\USER\.rustup

stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)
```

rustup target list does not list thumbv7m-none-eabi as installed

rustup target remove does not work either.

This results in me not being able to use the std library in any project whatsoever.

Comment: *"the thumbv7m-none-eabi target is in every rust project... This results in me not being able to use the std library..."* - can you clarify your symptoms with some compiler output? This is very odd

Comment: ```PS C:\Users\USER\Documents\coding\Euler\rust> cargo build -r --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
   Compiling rust v0.1.0 (C:\Users\USER\Documents\coding\Euler\rust)
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`

error: cannot find macro `println` in this scope
 --> src\main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     println!("Hello, world!");
  |     ^^^^^^^

error: requires `sized` lang_item

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `rust` due to 3 previous errors```

Comment: VSCode says: can't find crate for `std`
the `thumbv7m-none-eabi` target may not be installed
consider downloading the target with `rustup target add thumbv7m-none-eabi`

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED:

Vscode settings.json was set to add --target thumbv7m-none-eabi for some reason.

Thats why reinstalls fixed nothing and i was just going insane